# check if value (Accountnumber) exist in a java database

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have the following method in a class called savings, am using JDBC database to save and view data on java application.

I have SAVINGS table in my database **ZaiLab** with the following fields,

```
ID,ACCOUNTNUMBER,CUSTOMERNAME,BALANCE,MINMUM)
```

and the following VALUEs will be entered by the user using JOPtionPane.

```
(id,accountNumber,customername,balance,minmum);
```

the application should then check if **accountNumber** entered by the user already exist, if not it should save the record to a table SAVINGS, if yes it should display the appropriate message. "Account already exist".

```
public void openSavingsAccount(int Id, int Amount) {

    try {
        String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/ZaiLab";
        String uname = "siduduzo";
        String upass = "Password01";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uname, upass);

        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

        String SQL = "SELECT * FROM SAVINGS";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);

        int minmum = 1000;
        balance = minmum;

        while (rs.next()) {
            int acc_col = rs.getInt("ACCOUNTNUMBER");
            if (acc_col == accountNumber) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry, account " + accountNumber
                        + " aready Exist");
            } else if (Amount < minmum) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Can not Open the Account, Minimum amount to deposit must be R1000");
            } else {

                balance = balance + Amount;
                id = Id;
                stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO `SAVINGS`(ID,ACCOUNTNUMBER,CUSTOMERNAME,BALANCE,MINMUM)VALUE ('" + id + "','" + accountNumber + "','" + customername + "'," + balance + ",'" + minmum + "')");

            }

        }

    } catch (SQLException err) {
        System.out.println(err.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Comment: So what's the problem? You don't say?

Comment: sorry, the problem is. I have more than one record in my table **savings** and the first record has an accountnumber ** 2525** and the second record accountnumber is 3333, if the user enters account number 2525 the message "account already exist " is displayed, but if a user enter 3333 nothing happens, and it can not save to the database

Comment: account number 3333 is the second record in my database, and 2525 is the first record

Comment: Why are you selecting all rows, instead of just doing a `select ... from .. where accountnumber = ?` (where the `?` parameter is set to the account number)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you are selecting all rows from `SAVINGS` and attempt to insert a new account for each row that doesn't have the 'new' account number.

Instead, you should select only the row with the new account number, and insert when it doesn't exist.

You should also use prepared statements to protect you against SQL injection.

For example:

```
try (PreparedStatement checkAccountExists = con.prepareStatement(
        "SELECT 1 FROM SAVINGS WHERE ACCOUNTNUMBER = ?")) {
    checkAccountExists.setInt(1, accountNumber);

    try (ResultSet rs = checkAccountExists.executeQuery()) {
        if (rs.next()) {
            // handle account already exists
        } else {
            try (PreparedStatement insert = con.prepareStatement(
                    "INSERT INTO SAVINGS(ID, ACCOUNTNUMBER, CUSTOMERNAME, BALANCE, MINMUM) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ? , ?)")) {
                insert.setInt(1, id);
                insert.setInt(2, accountNumber);
                insert.setString(3, customername);
                insert.setInt(4, balance);
                insert.setInt(5, minmum);

                insert.executeUpdate();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could define a unique constraint on `ACCOUNTNUMBER` in your database and just do the insert and handle the constraint violation if the record already exists.

Comment: when I try to write this code, it say the variable rs (try (ResultSet rs = checkAccountExists.executeQuery())) already exist. mybe am editing the code wrong

Comment: @SiduduzoGodfreyManqele Don't just copy/paste my answer: if you already have a variable called `rs`, then either give it another name, or try to remove the other `rs` definition.

Comment: lol, I give up...this is what I get Lexical error at line 1, column 13.  Encountered: "`" (96), after : "". ... any way I was told not to use a database but I thought it is an easiest way to finish this project

Comment: @SiduduzoGodfreyManqele That is because you are not using MySQL (I have removed that tag from the question), but Derby according to the JDBC URL you use. The use of backticks like in `\`SAVINGS\`` is valid in MySQL, but in other database systems you should use double quotes instead (although in this case it might not even be necessary).

Comment: thank you so much Mark, you are a star. I removed the single quote on the 'Savings' and I managed to save to the database. still check some other issues though. might need your help later. thanks again for your help

Comment: @SiduduzoGodfreyManqele You're welcome. I do suggest that if you run into a new problem, that you create a new question.

Comment: lol @YCF_L  , MarkRotteveel will do that, sometimes it doesn't allow me. will say You have reached your question limit

Comment: Mark please search user @mcquelle he posted a question that I also need help with. I will appreciate if you could help  the question is tittle is Update a record value in java database

Comment: cc @YCF_L please also check

Comment: what is that @SiduduzoGodfreyManqele i don't get it?