# Update a record value in java database

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have the following method in a class called savings, am using JDBC database to save and update on java application.

I have SAVINGS table in my database ZaiLab with the following fields,
    ID,ACCOUNTNUMBER,CUSTOMERNAME,BALANCE,MINMUM)

and the following VALUEs will be entered by the user using JOPtionPane.
    (acc,Amount);

the application should then check if acco entered by the user  exist, if not it should display the appropriate message. "Account does not exist". If exist it should add Amount entered by the user Balance.

The problem is, it says There is no column named: BALANCE.

```
public void deposit(int acc,int Amount) {
    try {
        String host= "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/ZaiLab";
        String uname= "siduduzo";
        String upass ="Password01";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( host, uname, upass );

        Statement stmt = con.createStatement( );

        if(Amount<1000) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null,"Sorry! the Minimum you can deposit on a savings account is R1000");          
        } else {
            try (PreparedStatement checkAccountExists = con.prepareStatement("SELECT 1 FROM SAVINGS WHERE ACCOUNTNUMBER = ?")) {
                checkAccountExists.setInt(1, acc);

                try (ResultSet RS = checkAccountExists.executeQuery()) {
                    int currentbal = RS.getInt("BALANCE");
                    int newbalance = currentbal+Amount;

                    if (RS.next()) {
                        String sql = "UPDATE SAVINGS WHERE ACCOUNTNUMBER =" +acc+ "SET BALANCE = "+newbalance;
                        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null,"you have made a deposit to "+acc);
                    } else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null,"Invalid Account Number");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch ( SQLException err ) {
        System.out.println( err.getMessage( ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel  please help

Comment: This is what you get when you copy an answer to a [specific question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42454582/check-if-value-accountnumber-exist-in-a-java-database) without understanding what the code does. Also note that the way you are performing the update is not safe, it is open to SQL injection. Use a prepared statement, just like I did for the insert in my answer that you copied.

Comment: Am not sure if i follow, can you copy and paste the code above and add your suggestion. as a second answer. yes i copied your code because it is simalilar problem that i am trying to resolve.

Comment: managed to update, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently your `UPDATE` query is not valid if your database follows ANSI standards as the `WHERE` clause must follow the `SET` clause. Additionally, you need to space out clauses properly as now `SET` sits against account number. Such syntax can be best achieved with a prepared statement:

```sql
UPDATE SAVINGS SET BALANCE = ? WHERE ACCOUNTNUMBER = ?
```

And as @MarkRotteveel explains, assign *currentbal* and *newbalance* after checking for `RS.next()` to advance cursor in successful resultset query. Consider adjustment of your method's `else` block:

```
try (PreparedStatement checkAccountExists = con.prepareStatement(
        "SELECT BALANCE FROM SAVINGS WHERE ACCOUNTNUMBER = ?")) {
     checkAccountExists.setInt(1, acc);

     try (ResultSet RS = checkAccountExists.executeQuery()) {
          if (RS.next()) {
              int currentbal = RS.getInt("BALANCE");
              int newbalance = currentbal + Amount;

              try (PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(
                    "UPDATE SAVINGS SET BALANCE = ? WHERE ACCOUNTNUMBER = ?")){ 

                   stmt.setInt(1, newbalance);
                   stmt.setInt(2, acc);

                   stmt.executeUpdate();
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "you have made a deposit to "+acc);
              }

          } else {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Account Number");
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The query you fire goes:

```
SELECT 1 FROM SAVINGS WHERE ACCOUNTNUMBER = ?
```

and you populate the parameter marker's host variable with :

```
checkAccountExists.setInt(1, acc);
```

Now, if you specified an existing account number, the query above returns the value 1 with whatever default column name the underlying database uses as the column name. It will surely not be `BALANCE`. So you don't have that column in your result set.

If the `SAVINGS` table contains the column `BALANCE`, all you have to do is change the query in the string parameter of `con.prepareStatement` to :

```
SELECT BALANCE FROM SAVINGS WHERE ACCOUNTNUMBER = ?
```

In general: before you test your Java code - always try to connect to the underlying database using a plain SQL client - sqlplus in Oracle, vsql in Vertica, isql in SQL Server, etc. - and run such a query with an example parameter, to see what comes back. Then, you'd have found the error yourself.

Comment: hi Marco, thanks for your response. i have changed the parameter 'con.prepareStatement'  to: 'SELECT BALANCE FROM SAVINGS WHERE ACCOUNTNUMBER = ?' now its giving me the error  Invalid operation at current cursor position.

Comment: @mcquelle That is because you have not yet called the `next()` method on the result set when you call `RS.getInt("BALANCE")`. You need to move the call into the if block.

Comment: Am not sure if i follow, can you copy and paste the code above and add your suggestion. as a second answer

Answer (score 0):

It changes all records in the column to the same record

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM department INNER JOIN employee ON department.depno=employee.depno  ";
resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql); 

sql2="update employee set empage=? " ;  
ps=connection.prepareStatement(sql2);
while (resultSet.next()){  
    empage=resultSet.getInt("empage"); 
     if(empage>50){  l= empage-3; 
         //statement.executeUpdate(sql2); 
         ps.setInt(1,l);   
         ps.executeUpdate();
         ps.addBatch();
       }  
}
```